Focus UIList Filter Section By Default
I want to know if it’s possible to focus the filter textbox of a UIList by default when a floating panel opens, similar to how the filter textbox in context.window_manager.invoke_search_popup is automatically focused.
Currently, when the panel opens, we first have to click inside the filter textbox. However, invoke_search_popup automatically focuses the filter textbox, so there’s no need to click inside it.
Is there a programmatic way to achieve this behavior with UIList, or should I use invoke_search_popup instead?
Additionally, I’ve noticed an issue with UIList: When the UIList is in the NPanel section, hovering over it and pressing Ctrl+F correctly focuses the text cursor in the filter textbox. But when the UIList is in a floating panel, Ctrl+F doesn’t work.
How would you approach fixing this issue?

it seems not possible. but invoke_search_popup
